# VS 2017 - error al enviar Email con Script C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mail, ssis

Al ejecutar me aparece esta excepción:

```
  en System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   en System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: Hola @Pedro, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] de bienvenida de bienvenida para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: Específico a su error, proporcione el código. La excepción solo indica que se encontró un error. Demasiado genérico de una falla sin código fuente.